# Jave program FTP transfers fail when DST is enabled

Tags: java, ftp, dst, ftp-client

I have a Java program that connects to a FTP server running on IIS (unknown version until the vendor responds) Both of our servers are on Windows Server. Mine is running on 2012 and 2012 R2, but the vendor's OS version is unknown, but I would assume 2008 or newer.

It's been running fine until DST kicked in and here's what I know so far:

My server connects --> Provider's FTP server and tries to download a list of files.

BOTH my server and the providers server have their time zones set as Eastern Time Zone.
When my server connects, it CAN download files from certain folders, but not other folders.

Here's where it gets more weird, because I just assumed it's a permissions issue of some sort on a particular folder, but that doesn't look to be the cause.

WHEN I change my server's time zone to Arizona and run my same application without any changes, IT WORKS without any issues!?

Why is this and how can it be fixed without flipping the time zone back and forth?

The java program is just using standard ftp.connect and didn't have an issue until DST went into affect. I can manually download the files using a 3rd party program like FileZilla while being set to EST and DST enabled on my server's OS so I'm not sure where to look next? The only thing that I can think of is that it's somehow trying to convert the time stamps when both are on EST after DST takes affect and Arizona ignores it, but why would that be the case only within certain folders on the vendor's FTP server?

Comment: "When my server connects, it CAN download files from certain folders, but not other folders." What happens when it tries? Does it get error messages? What do the errors say? Can you [edit] your question to include the relevant source code?

Comment: It throws a null pointer, but only when the time zone is set to EST w/ DST. I  will have to request a stripped version of the source and it may take literally forever to get approval to release. It's got to be something with the conversion of UTC from within the filesystems somehow.

Comment: Without some code, it's going to be off-topic for this site.  Can you provide code for your Java application, or an [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reproduces the problem against a standard IIS or other FTP server?